# js-routes ASP.NET MVC alternative

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, js-routes

So, I have been tasked with rewriting a prototype ruby app back-end to .NET, and have stumbled onto a gem called js-routes.  You can read about this here: https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/

This gem appears to generate JavaScript objects for all the routes that were defined in the ruby app.  I need to see if there is something that is similar in the ASP.NET MVC world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check these options:

[ASP.NET MVC JavaScript Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx)

[JsAction](https://jsaction.codeplex.com/)